# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV]

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, jstl

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix = "c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <h3>Example of Tag lib Directive</h3>
        <hr>
        <c:set var = "name" value="Software Engineer"></c:set>
        <c:out value = "${name}"></c:out>

    </body>
</html>
```

Above is my JSP code and it is showing me a notification in my netbeans 12.6 version in down left corner.

> servlet api classes are not on the classpath, some scriptlet editing features are disabled

This is my tomcat server notification.

```
Type Exception Report

Message org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV]
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:589)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:425)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV]
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:54)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:142)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createValidator(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:360)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:195)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:429)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:487)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1444)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:245)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:106)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause
```